# Array of tuples to JSON (TypeScript) not recognized by API entry point

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, api

I have an angular application that call my back-end written in Asp.net c#. The back-end works correctly (already used by a mobile application) but one entry point does not behave correctly while being hit by the angular Application.

I Serialize a tupple array of  and send it to the API, but when API entry point gets hit, it seems like the data of the tuple array is not being received.

I've already looked to my tuple array, the data is correctly serialized to json client-side but not received server-side.

Here is the entry point definition in my c# API :

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Xamarin_UpdateStatut([FromRoute] int idEvent,          [System.Web.Http.FromBody] List<Tuple<int, bool>> listUsersStatut)
    {
    }
```

And here is the tuple sended client-side (get via chrome console) :
       "[[2102,false],[1096,false],[73,false]]"

Here is the code used to serialized the tuple array to Json (client-side) :

```
 var listUpdate = new Array<[number, boolean]>();
arr.forEach(re => {
  let el: [number, boolean] = [re.userId, re.wasThere];
  listUpdate.push(el);
});
let body = JSON.stringify(listUpdate);
```

I debugged a few times server side, the list length is 0. I tried to change the type received from List to Tuple array (server side, in the method definition) but it didn't change anything.

It seems to me like the json output is correct so I don't understand why it does not work.

A little help would be very much appreciated :)

Have a nice day and thanks in advance,

Lio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples in C# are treated like classes, whereas you're setting up your client-side model as if they're arrays. Try something like this:

```
 var listUpdate = new Array<{item1: number, item2: boolean}>();
arr.forEach(re => {
  let el: {item1: number, item2: boolean} = {item1: re.userId, item2: re.wasThere};
  listUpdate.push(el);
});
```

I'd personally suggest using a strongly-typed class instead of tuples, so you have more meaningful property names than `Item1` and `Item2`.

You might also consider posting an object that has the list as one of its properties rather than posting the list itself: this will give you the flexibility to add more data to the object in the future, should the need arise, without needing to change as much code.

Answer (score 0):

Binding happens by name. From [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2):
"MVC will try to bind request data to the action parameters by name. MVC will look for values for each parameter using the parameter name and the names of its public settable properties."

In order for binding to be successful, the names in your JSON must match the names of the C# parameters, including the names of the properties of each parameter.